# Change the system class loader at runtime

Tags: java, classloader

Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Class load
        A a = new A();
        a.msg();
    }
}
```

A class

```
public class A {
    public void msg() {
      System.out.println("msg");
    }
}
```

I have written code in the main class that calls a msg() method of class A

After I created the jar file, I pull out A.class.

Then the path will have a jar file with missing A.class, and A.class.

```
A a = new A();
a.msg();
```

How do I dynamically load and run A.class without making any changes to the above code?

Please help me..

Comment: I think the JVM will be expecting `A.class` to be in the location whence you removed it.  Hence, your code will fail.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: what's the purpose of removing/pulling the A.class after becoming JAR?

Comment: I wanted to get the bytecode of the class from the local network and load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to load a class dynamically. I would recommend you to create a jar and load it using `URIClassLoader`. There is a really good answer here:- [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

A.class has to be in the classpath somewhere for the code to run. you can put it in a jar of its own, and add the second jar to the classpath. Then the class loader can find it.

Comment: I want to get the bytecode of the class on the local network and load it. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't know how to dynamically load class bytecode.